# Why does Qt change behaviour of sscanf()?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, qt4, scanf

I have noticed, Qt (4.8) changes the behaviour of `sscanf()`. Without Qt `sscanf()` works as usual, but with, it takes only localized strings.

Here's a minimized example:

---

### Without Qt (plain C++)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float f;
    sscanf("0.83", "%f", &f);

    std::cout << f << "\t-->\t" << typeid("0.83").name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.83    -->     A5_c
```

(given string is a 5x `char`-array, result correct)

---

### With Qt

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
     * This breaks sscanf() for the whole (!) project
     * and linked libraries too!
     */
    QApplication(argc, argv);

    float f;
    sscanf("0.83", "%f", &f);

    std::cout << f << "\t-->\t" << typeid("0.83").name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0       -->     A5_c
```

(Given string still a 5x `char`-array, but result is wrong)

---

While `0.83` fails, using `0,83` (my locale format) works fine with Qt - but fails without Qt (default behaviour). As shown by  `typeid()`, there's no `QString` used - only plain old C(++) char-arrays. Btw., same happens to `std::string`.

Beside this, using a `std::stringstream` keeps working as normal:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "0.83"; // But the value into the stream
ss >> f;      // Get a float out of it
```

**Result:**

```
0.83
```

**And here comes the question:** Why are char-array strings and `sscanf()` calls affected by Qt? I understand why `QString`'s are localized, but breaking`sscanf()` (and potentially other `stdio.h` functions) sounds evil to me.

*Background:* I linked a (non-Qt) library, containing a `sscanf()` somewhere deep in the code, to a Qt project. Result: Some code failed in this project, while it worked everywhere else … (took some time to find the cause …)

Comment: Thanks for the question! It tooks me a while to find out the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general terms if you get a function, in the standard library, that has something to do with streams or I/O operations, chances are that it's gonna be affected by your locale settings.

This is true for `sscanf` and in your case Qt is overriding the default `C locale` that you usually get when using the default C/C++ configuration.

you should use

`setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C")`

right after initializing your Qt environment, in this case after `QApplication`.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#locale-settings

to set things back to what you expect .

Comment: I see ... in some cases it may be a good thing, if locales are set per default, but in my case this caused *a conflict with POSIX functions* (as said in your link). However, setting back the locale works fine and doesn't brake gui components on the other hand. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: No, don't do that. Just call uselocale() before reading and writing saved data if you're using an ad-hoc text based format parsed by the standard C-library functions & then set it back to the user locale afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect QT sets the locale automatically based on your system locale. There's actually a [standard localization library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale).

Setting the C locale changes the behavior of a bunch of functions, listed [on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale).

Note however, that C++ streams do *not* automatically pick up the C locale, which is why your `std::stringstream` is behaving normally.

Comment: Very good point! I thought (string-)streams would use locales too, so this looked all odd to me. So is it in general safer to use those streams instead of e.g. `sscanf()` for such parsing things (which are not using any local format)?

Comment: You can always check the C locale if you need. Honestly, I have very little experience dealing with localized code, so I'm not sure of the pitfalls you might find.

Answer (score 2):

Qt is calling setlocale to set the C runtuime to use your locale. You could try setting it back with setlocale(LC_ALL, “C”); but I'm not sure how that would affect the rest of Qt.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I just checked gui components (like double spinboxes), they seem to keep their local format, while `sscanf()` works (again).