# vtkOBJReader dosen't work inside qt main loop

Tags: python, c++, qt, vtk

I have a strange issue with reading OBJ file using VTK in Python. Code example below works fine for me.

```
reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()
reader.SetFileName('cube.obj')
reader.Update()
inputP = reader.GetOutput()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow(inputP)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but if I first initialize **QApplication**, then **vtkOBJReader** throw an error message:

> ERROR: In /build/vtk/src/VTK-6.1.0/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx, line 192
>   vtkOBJReader (0x56396fd14fa0): Error reading 'v' at line 5

Example code that does not work is shown below:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()
reader.SetFileName('cube.obj')
reader.Update()
inputP = reader.GetOutput()

window = MainWindow(inputP)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have the same issue if I wrote this program in C++.
Have you any suggestions, how to force **vtkOBJReader** to work inside QT app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the same exact problem and studying the code from vtkObjectReader (link: https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx#L264) you can see the error message is produced inside this snippet:

```
// this is a vertex definition, expect three floats, separated by whitespace:
if (sscanf(pLine, "%f %f %f", xyz, xyz+1, xyz+2) == 3)
  {
    points->InsertNextPoint(xyz);
    numPoints++;
  }
  else
  {
    vtkErrorMacro(<<"Error reading 'v' at line " << lineNr);
    everything_ok = false;
  }
```

the problem is due to sscanf giving a different output if it is called before or after qt initialization.
With this information i found the solution here: [Why does Qt change behaviour of sscanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555696/why-does-qt-change-behaviour-of-sscanf)

With qt the locale used to parse the line is the same of your system (mine is italian so it was expecting "," as a decimal divider not a "." so it failed to recognize the float type).

if you change the locale after the definition of you QApplication it works as intended, i.e:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may help someone. Load the object file before initialize the QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv).

Comment: I want to allow the user to select OBJ file via QFileDialog. So it does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

In python, this problem can be solved by changing the locale after the definition of you QApplication:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'C')
mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This resource may help you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html